# Html-loader + file-loader not bundling the correct image source

Tags: html, webpack, webpack-file-loader, webpack-html-loader, webpack-bundle

I'm planning to use Webpack for a project and I'm setting up my workflow with Html-loader + file-loader to get a production html file with dynamic src for the images, as Colt Steele teaches in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpGLUVbqoYQ&t=1348s). Here are my src/ files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Popular on Letterboxd</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="./assets/chira.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
import img from './assets/chira.jpg';
import "./main.css";
```

And main.css

```
body {
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

These are my config files (I have an individual for dev and production and a common for both):

webpack.common.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',

  devtool: "none",
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ["html-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
              publicPath: 'assets',
              outputPath: 'assets/img'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

webpack.dev.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  },
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
});
```

And webpack.prod.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const merge = require('webpack-merge');


module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "main.[contentHash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
});
```

However, when I run npm run build, which executes this command:

```
"build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
```

And I get the expected dist folder with assets/img/[name].[hash].[ext], but in my index.html I do not get the expected src tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Popular on Letterboxd</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="[object Module]" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.e55bd4ff82bf2f5cec90.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I've been trying to fix the problem for a while now, but I can't seem to get a proper answer anywhere, and nothing that I've tried have worked so far. I would appreciate if anyone who has encountered this problem can address how they fixed it, or if someone has any clue of what the problem might be and what can I do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try`<img src="/assets/chira.jpg" />` without `dot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If file-loader verions is 5.0 then. Adding another option on file-loader as "esModule: false" will solve this problem.

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
          publicPath: 'assets',
          outputPath: 'assets/img',
          esModule: false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

**If you are using webpack 5** or later, the `file-loader` is depricated. [File loader documentation](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/)
You could use the module `asset/resource` instead. Remove your `file-loader` rule and add the following rule to your module in webpack.common.js

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
            type: 'asset/resource'
        }
    ]
},
```

then add `assetModuleFilename` in the `output` in your webpack.prod.js

```
output: {
    assetModuleFilename: "assets/img/[name].[hash][ext]"
}
```

and keep your `html-loader` rule in the webpack.common.js as it is.

References [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/)