# Webpack doesn't load inline background-image

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

This is the rule for the image loader

```
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      },
```

This is the rule for the html loader

```
test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: {
              minimize: true
            }
          }
```

every other images are loaded fine, except for the inline background images

```html
<div class="ms__slide" style="background-image: url('../images/slider-bg.jpg')">

      </div>
```

Comment: How do you use your template? Looks like you have to use this loader as well https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/

Comment: i use this loader too, everything works perfectly, i just need the inline background images to get loaded aswell

Comment: This option https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#attributes allows you to require your image gets extracted in the build. It's supposed to be working. Can you share more about your code?

Comment: Why don't you edit your question? I'm also keen to know where you import your html?

Comment: i edited it, what do you mean where do I import my html?

Comment: Yeah. That's I want to see

Comment: no you didn't understand, what do you mean by "where do i import my html"?

Comment: I meant you can you include above html into the bundle? Is that located in index.html or a template of component?

Comment: it is located into the index.html

Comment: Check this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59062150/html-loader-file-loader-not-bundling-the-correct-image-source

Comment: doesnt' work either

Comment: that question isn't similar at all, he has problems with a regular img tag, I have problems with inline background-image

Comment: Have you set up a repo yet? If so, is it accessible? So I can have a look then

Comment: no, I can't because of the privacy policy of the website

Comment: Or you can just simply create a reproducible repo with minimal of code which ends up with the issue then I can help with

Answer (score 0):

Add also a css loader:

```
npm install --save-dev css-loader
```

Somewhere in rule section:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'css-loader' 
}
```

Comment: i have all the loaders i need, the problem is only with the background-image

Comment: it works only when the url() is in css, it doesn't work with the inline css